# How to make a BattleShips game?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How do I make a Battleships game for the Iphone?

I'm new to programming, I've done some tutorials and I feel I'm making progress with this but I would like to make a full game like battleships.

Can anyone help me out with this?

I'm trying to learn cocos2d-Iphone so I would like to use that if possible.
David

Comment: Like, the whole thing? From start to finish? What have you done so far towards it?

Comment: -1, doesn't seem like a real question.  Probably off topic.

Comment: I've been playing around with cocos2d, made a bunch of tutorials, simple games from tutorials, reading, trying different things with xcode and interfacebuilder, learning photoshop.....

I want to know if there is source code to look at as a reference, someone to tutor me and teach me the tricks, help me solve problems etc.

Comment: My suspicion is that the question you should be asking is not "How to make a battleships game" - because if you're familiar enough with programming, battleships will be easy. Instead, as bummzack suggested, start with something ridiculously simple.

Answer (score 4):

Since you already started learning, why not go ahead and try to implement something? Maybe start with a simpler game-concept (like [Tic-Tac-Toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe)) to get a grip of all the things involved (code, graphics, sound, etc.). Then post more specific questions here as you move along. Since your question is a bit "broad" to say the least.